# MSVC compiler identification with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, version

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 version 15.3.0 and CMake version 3.8.1.

Running `cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64" .` gives

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 17.0.60610.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 17.0.60610.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
```

But running `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe` gives

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x64
```

So exactly which version of the compiler is this using? 17.0.60610.1 or 17.00.50727.1?

Comment: Its using 17.00.50727.1.

Comment: @drescherjm Why does CMake reports MSVC 17.0.60610.1? Where does this version number come from?

Comment: ***Where does this version number come from?*** I think that is the default compiler before it set the generator. I have seen some anomalies like that in the past.

Comment: Does it do this if you run cmake from a Visual Studio 2012 x64 command prompt.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, CMake's output is identical when run from a VS 2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt.